# How to launch a php script 12 hours after each user triggered event

Tags: php

Any of the users can trigger an event, as many times they wish. Each time this event is triggered, a row in a mysql table is created with the timestamp, their userid and other useful information. What I need to do is launch a script which runs exactly 12 hours after the event is triggered i.e. for each row in the table.

How can I achieve this in an automated and efficient fashion?

Comment: You'll have to set a cron job. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: cron job? at job? hire someone to sit there and watch the clock?

Comment: Funny. check the link I posted.

Comment: Why exactly 12 hours? Is "about" 12 hours ok? Is a low time after 12 hours ok (eg, 12 hours and 5 minutes)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a cron job which every minute launches the script.

In the script you should first fetch the row(s) and check if it's OK to run (if 12 hours passed) then continue, else stop.

I don't know if this will be very efficient, it depends on your number of entries in the database, but technically it's not expensive to just check if the current date matches a date fetched from the database + 12 hrs, I cannot say more because you didn't give too much details about your data.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be better off with a cronjob

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Potentially, you could look into MySQL event scheduler. Although It might not fit your needs, hard to really tell on the details given

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

something like

```
CREATE EVENT myTimedEvent ON SCHEDULE EVERY INTERVAL 5 minutes DO CALL updateRows();
```

updateRows checks your criteria (12hours ago), if it is, perform whatever action you want to do. This requires your MySQL to be @ version 5.1+ however

Answer (score 0):

You would probably best have a cron job which runs every minute and checks for any rows in the database > 12 hours old that have not yet been processed the script and process them.  This wont give you EXACTLY a 12 hour difference, but would give you a difference within a minute of that.

You would probably also want to make sure that script would  be able to run within a few seconds such that you don't have overlap of the script running twice at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using CronJobs. If you have root access to your Server or a server administration toolkit that offers cronjob managment you would do it on your server. otherwise use an online cronjob service (google for cronjob online).

the cronjob then triggers a php script on your server in your defined interval, like every minute or every 5 minutes.

this script then selects all rows from your mysql table which are older then 12 hours (`WHERE timestamp <= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 hour` ) and performs your desired actions on each result and delete the result from the table (or mark it done),

just make sure that the fetching and the actions itself are faster than your cronjob interval, otherwise you would have two or more scripts working on the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way for me is to make the page head contains

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="43200"> <!-- 43200 for (12 hours × 60 mintes × 60 seconds)  -->
</head>
```

**This method is very helpful to avoid server time out, which you can't avoid if you are using only PHP code**

**Important** if you start the script using submit button, it's recommended to make the form `action="other_page"` not the same page, and sure you should save your input values as cookie using [setcookie](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp) function and grab it as a variable in the action page using `$cookieVar = $_COOKIE['the_cookie_name'] ;`

You may need to increase or decrease the $cookieVar value and update the value again using setcookie every time your head code `http-equiv` do the refresh automatically after the specific seconds (43200 in our example) depends on what you want to do

Note that if you make your action start automatically without pressing submit button you can do the action in the same page.

I did that idea before, I had 180,000 images in one folder and the server didn't allow me to download it all because it was showing me only first 7998 images, so I create a script to zip each 1000 image in a file outside the images folder and to avoid time out, I made the code refresh each 60 second , finally I got only 180 zip file :)